# How to add URL encoder and character encoder in vaadin

Tags: vaadin

i have Vaadin application which read URL parameter and show on label the value of URL parameter

But its not supporting for Scandinavian character.

any one have idea how to configure URL character encoding and decoding in vaadin

The application URL is something like this

```
http://localhost:7001/csa?address="måndag";
```

in Vaadin UI i am getting address value as `request.getParameter("address")`

and set the value on label

but somehow vaadin failes to parse the URL with exception. The exception is like

```
Java.net.URLSyntexException: Illegal character in query
```

I am using maven for build and deployment as war on local weblogic server

so anyone have idea how to support these character in vaadin

Comment: could you please provide code samples, how the label's value is set, how you pass the params (e.g. the URL) and what encoding you are using

Comment: i have sample URL in browser is like http://localhost:7001/csa?address="få tillgång"

Comment: I am getting the parameter as request.getParameter("address"); and on label set value as what i got from parameter.

Comment: please edit the question and add everything there. comments can not hold all informations and make it hard for someone to get a quick grasp of the question. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28942462/edit

Comment: if there are exceptios, please add them to the question.  every little bit is helpfull

Comment: and just in case, please alos add, how you run your code (e.g. in what container, as war or just started in ide, ...)